# Is there a way to list drive letters in dired?

Tags: windows, emacs, dired

On windows, how could I open a dired buffer showing all drive letters. When you do <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> you should always provide a directory, but I want to start at the drive letters level instead of a root directory of a particular drive.

If no standard solution exists, do you have one (an extension to dired ?) ? or links to articles on the subject ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In dired you can only view directories, and since no directory exists which contains your drive letters, you can't see a list of them.

To do this you'd have to write an emacs-lisp extension for dired.

AFAIK there's no existing extension, however, a call to **wmic** can give you a listing of drive letters and volume names, which would be a good starting point.

The **wmic** command:

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,drivetype,providername,volumename
```

Calling it from emacs-lisp and getting the result as a string.

```
(let (sh-output volumes)
  (setq sh-output (shell-command-to-string "wmic LogicalDisk get Caption,DriveType,ProviderName,VolumeName"))
)
```

Will give you a list of the volumes (DriveType : 3 = HDD, 4 = Network Mapping, 5 = Optical.)

However, you can't get dired to recognize a buffer with this output, so you'd need to create a major mode for browsing windows volumes, which would show this listing and bind <kbd>RET</kbd> to find the drive letter on the current line and do a dired at it's root.

If you just want the drive letters listed...

```
(let (sh-output volumes)
  (setq sh-output (shell-command-to-string "wmic LogicalDisk get Caption"))
)
```

Will do that.

Comment: I have edited my question to ask for any existing solution to this problem or links to articles on the subject.

Comment: @Jerome, try wmic to get the text output you need for the drives.

Comment: @Jerome, I'm back on a Windows box so I'll have a look quickly see if I can do something too.

Answer (score 2):

**Dired+** has what you want.

Command `diredp-w32-drives` opens a list/menu of the Windows drives. Use <kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>mouse-2</kbd> to open Dired on one of the drives. The local drives come from option `diredp-w32-local-drives`, which you can customize.

If you hit <kbd>^</kbd> in Dired when visiting one of your drives (e.g. `C:\`), then you get to the same list/menu of all drives.